# Unable to identify which type of post User Profile Stats standard component counts

Tags: community, chatter, customer-community, chatter-feed, user-profile

I have created the custom user profile stats that can be seen below as Influence Custom. 
The purpose of creating the replica is to make text under the count clickable and when users click on the link it can show the list of the respective item records.

Everything is done except this one issue that you can see in the screen snap that standard one shows the different number of the post then the custom one.

I am trying to figure out what type of posts standard component retrieves so that I can filter the same post in the custom component.

I am using ConnectAPI.ChatterUser Class to show followers and following.

and for Post, Comment and Like I am doing SOQL on FeedItem and FeedComment.

I am using the following method to show the list of the post.

```
 @AuraEnabled    
public static List<FeedItem> getPostList(String userId, String type)
{

    List<FeedItem> fItems = new List<FeedItem>();

    if(type == 'comment')
    {
        system.debug('Comment');
        Set<Id> feedItemComment = new Set<Id>();
        List<FeedComment> fComment = [SELECT Id, CreatedById, FeedItemId, InsertedById, CommentBody FROM FeedComment where InsertedById =:userId];
        for(FeedComment fcom : fComment)
        {
            feedItemComment.add(fcom.FeedItemId);
        }

        fItems = [SELECT ID, CreatedDate, CreatedById, CreatedBy.FirstName, CreatedBy.LastName, ParentId, Parent.Name, Body, InsertedById, Type, Title, LinkUrl, LikeCount
        FROM FeedItem Where Id in: feedItemComment];
    }
    else if(type == 'like')
    {
        system.debug('Like');
        fItems = [SELECT ID, CreatedDate, CreatedById, CreatedBy.FirstName, CreatedBy.LastName, ParentId, Parent.Name, Body, InsertedById, Type, Title, LinkUrl,  LikeCount
        FROM FeedItem Where CreatedById =: userId and LikeCount > 0 ];

    }
    else if(type == 'post')
    {
        system.debug('Post');
        fItems = [SELECT ID, CreatedDate, CreatedById, CreatedBy.FirstName, CreatedBy.LastName, ParentId, Parent.Name, Body, InsertedById, Type, Title, LinkUrl,  LikeCount
        FROM FeedItem Where CreatedById =: userId];

    }

    return fItems;

}
```

[image]